# "Access Denied", link to .php from .php, but OK from .htm?

Tags: php, nginx, access-denied

Running nginx and php5 on Raspberry Pi 3B running Raspbian Jessie.  I have a .php script/page "activepage.php" that is linked from index.php.  When link to activepage.php is clicked from index.php, I get "Access Denied".  HOWEVER, if I put the SAME link into index.htm, the page (activepage.php) loads just fine.

Related, I have within activepage.php a javascript that calls a new XMLHttpRequest() to another .php file (scandir.php) which lists files in the directory.  No doubt due to the above issue, the call to scandir.php returns nothing.

Somewhat new to nginx and php on Linux.  Everything I have works perfectly on windows servers on "regular" hosting in the wild...  I suspect I have some sort of path or user permissions issues, but I'm just not sure where at this point, my searches don't reveal anything that I can interpret meaningfully.  Need some guidance.

Thanks.

UPDATE:  I have figured out this much:  ANY page named index (.htm or .php) will work.  Any page NOT named index, will not.  So ... is there an "allowable filename" setting somewhere?  If I copy activepage.php and name it index.php, it runs.  If I rename it to test.php, I get "Access Denied".

UPDATE AGAIN:  Issue resolved.  Permissions issue, had to:
sudo chmod -R a+r /var/www/html
Everything's working now.  Just need to determine why new files have wrong perms when I FTP them up.

Thanks all.

Comment: Check the access log to see what URL you're actually trying to access.

Comment: I would have to agree with Barmar. Also, check your html from the html file and from your PHP file side by side. Is there a possibility that one is linked relative to the current page and that one has an absolute URL? Do you get the same URL when you hover over both links?

Comment: The link URL when I hover shows the exact same for both: 192.168.1.201/activepage.php.  I have two files, index.php and index.htm, that I have also set up cross-links in - and they link to each other just fine (htm to php and php to htm).  See also edit above regarding new behavior as of restart this morning.  Baffling...